# What is the proper/preferred way for an Angular component to expose an API (in a library)?

Tags: angular

Consider this oversimplified component:

> test.component.html

```html
<button>{{buttonData}}</button>
```

> test.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
    buttonData: string = 'Test';

    changeButtonContents(data) {
        this.buttonData = data;
    }
}
```

Now, considering this other component:

> other.component.html

```html
<app-test></app-test>
```

What is the best way to expose an "API" from the `app-test` component? By API, I mean callable methods and settable variables. As far as I know, we can only pass in variables as `[property]='bindings'`

One way would be to `@ViewChild` it, but that "feels" wrong, and it also gives full access to the component, unlike exposing an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't expose "an API" (I will use it as the term so you understand better but is not the correct one), you can simply pass parameters from "Parent to Child" or "Child to Parent" or even disconnected components (two that are not "Parent/Child", but you need the parameter from A to be received on B)

In the case of `@ViewChild`, it's the way that you can "set/handle" information based on the "handler" you set, so you can control certain information like `nativeElement`.

For the Parent, as you said `[property]="'value'"` and internally you use `@Input()`

So in this case, `@Input()` refers to the value that the component receives from the parent, and on the other hand, you have `@Output`, so the child can send values to the parent.

Finally the third case, you can use `BehaviorSubject` combined with a service, so you can "listen" to events, and then, connect two components that don't have relations like:

```
<app-my-general-component>
   <component-a></component-a>
   <component-b></component-b>
</app-my-general-component>
```

So `<component-a>` can communicate with `<component-b>`

Finally, if you need to use a certain function that can modify values in another component, then, do it using services, not the component functions itself, and connect both through that service.

So there you go, in conclusion:

- If you need a child to receive information from the parent, use
  `@Input()`
- If you need a child to send information to the parent, use
  `@Output()`
- If you need two components to connects, use
  `BehaviourSubject`

Check the official docs:
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think @ViewChild approach is not good? Take an example of material button. It has a method called `focus()` using which consumers can focus a mat button.

Now how do a consumer call focus method? Using ViewChild right?

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" #btnRef="matButton">{{'recovery' | translate}}</button>
```

In component file

```
@ViewChild('btnRef') buttonRef: MatButton;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.buttonRef.focus();
}
```

Take another example of material select, it has a open method:

```
 <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

How do we access the API?

```
 ...
 @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect;
  ...
  click() {
    this.mySelect.open();
  }
```

So in my opinion, it is fine to use the component API method using ViewChild. This is how we grab the component instance and invoke API method.